# Problemas al cerrar mi formulario en C# (se repite el mensaje de confirmacion)

Tags: c#, windows-forms, formularios

Mi problema radica en que mi formulario tiene un evento de cerrar y de echo lo hace correctamente siempre y cuando no me regrese a donde se delcaro dicho evento, esto quiere decir que mientras navegue por otras ventanas excepto en la inicial, me aparece el mensaje una sola vez y si regreso 2 o 3 veces al formulario inicial, la ventana de cierre al darle clic en la "x" me aparece 2 o 3 veces.

Codigo del evento:

```
//Metodo para cerrar la aplicacion cuando el usuario guste.
private void cierre(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CloseReason == CloseReason.UserClosing)
    {
        DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("¿Esta seguro de Que quiere cerrar la aplicacion?", "Cerrar la Aplicacion", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
        if (dialogResult != DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Codigo con el que avanzo a la siguiente ventana:

```
//Metodo para llevarme a la ventana de Modal_General
private void btnCompras_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Close();
    Modal_General general = new Modal_General();
    general.Show();
}
```

Codigo con el que regreso a mi formulario inicial.

```
 private void btnRegresar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
        Inicio inicio = new Inicio();
        inicio.Show();
    }
```

el codigo del evento Cierre se encuentra en mi formulario princiapl, y cuando me regreso a mi formulario inicial y doy clic en x, la ventana emergente de confirmacion se abre dos veces, no se si es porque tal vez aplico  `inicio.Closed += (s, args) => this.Close();`, para ir a la siguiente ventana y luego para regresar a la ventana inicial.

Ventana que aparece dos veces:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Codigo Completo del formulario al que avanza:

```
namespace Presupuesto_DaeboSoft
{
    public partial class Modal_General : Form
    {

        private MySqlConnection connection;
        string imgPath;
        string imagen;
        int conteo=0;
        string fecha="";


        //Metodo para obtener las imagenes actuales de tu sistema
        public void obtenerImagenes()
        {
            String Mes = DateTime.Now.Month.ToString();
            PictureBox[] pics = { Enero, Febrero, Marzo, Abril, Mayo, Junio, Julio, Agosto, Septiembre, Octubre, Noviembre, Diciembre };
            for (int i =0; i < Convert.ToInt32(Mes); i++)
            {
                imagen = pics[i].Name;
                var directorio = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(@"..\..\Imagenes\Imagenes_Modal\Usuario\" + imagen);
                if (directorio.Exists==true) {
                    conteo = directorio.GetFiles().Length-1;
                }


                    imgPath = @"..\..\Imagenes\Imagenes_Modal\Usuario\"+imagen+@"\"+imagen+conteo + ".jpeg";
                if (imgPath != null && Directory.Exists(@"..\..\Imagenes\Imagenes_Modal\Usuario\"+imagen) == true)
                {
                    pics[i].Image = Image.FromFile(imgPath);
                }
            }
        }


        //Metodo para no cambiar de tamaño el formulario y que se ejecute de forma central
        public void notSize()
        {
            this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedSingle;
            this.MaximizeBox = false;
            this.MinimizeBox = false;
            this.CenterToScreen();
        }


        //Constructor del Formulario
        public Modal_General()
        {
            Base_de_Datos.Conexion conn = new Base_de_Datos.Conexion();
            connection = conn.iniciarBD();

            InitializeComponent();

            obtenerImagenes();
            notSize();


            //Me genera un ciclo que rellena de imagenes los meses despues del actual.
            //Tambien me desabilita los botones de cambio inecesario.
            String Dia = DateTime.Now.Day.ToString();
            String Mes = DateTime.Now.Month.ToString();
            String Año = DateTime.Now.Year.ToString();

            fecha = Año + "-" + Mes + "-" + Dia;


            lblDia.Text = Dia;
            lblMes.Text = Mes;
            lblAño.Text = Año;
            PictureBox[] pics = { Enero, Febrero, Marzo, Abril, Mayo, Junio, Julio, Agosto, Septiembre, Octubre, Noviembre, Diciembre };
            Button[] botones = { btn1, btn2, btn3, btn4, btn5, btn6, btn7, btn8, btn9, btn10, btn11, btn12 };

            for (int MesE = Convert.ToInt16(Mes); MesE < pics.Length; MesE++)
            {
                pics[MesE].Image = Image.FromFile(@"..\..\Imagenes\Imagenes_Modal\Default\NoAplica.png");
                pics[MesE].Enabled = false;
                botones[MesE].Visible = false;

            }


        }



        private void Modal_General_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        //Eventos clic que llaman el metodo de cambiar imagen
        //*************************************************************************************\\
        private void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Cambiar_Imagen("Enero",Enero);
        }

        private void btn2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Cambiar_Imagen("Febrero",Febrero);
        }

        private void btn3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Cambiar_Imagen("Marzo",Marzo);
        }

        private void btn4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Cambiar_Imagen("Abril", Abril);
        }

        private void pic12_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Cambiar_Imagen("Diciembre", Diciembre);
        }

        private void pic6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Cambiar_Imagen("Junio", Junio);
        }

        private void pic7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Cambiar_Imagen("Julio", Julio);
        }

        private void pic8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Cambiar_Imagen("Agosto", Agosto);
        }

        private void pic9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Cambiar_Imagen("Septiembnre", Septiembre);
        }

        private void pic10_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Cambiar_Imagen("Octubre", Octubre);
        }

        private void pic11_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Cambiar_Imagen("Noviembre", Noviembre);
        }

        private void pic5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Cambiar_Imagen("Mayo", Mayo);
        }
        //*************************************************************************************\\


        //Metodo para cambiar la imagen del picturebox
        public void Cambiar_Imagen(string valor, PictureBox picture)
        {
            OpenFileDialog open = new OpenFileDialog();

            open.Filter = "Image Files(*.jpg; *.jpeg; *.gif;*.png)|*.jpg; *.jpeg; *.gif;*.png";
            if (open.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                string ext = Path.GetExtension(open.FileName);
                var fileInfo = new FileInfo(open.FileName);
                picture.Image = new Bitmap(open.FileName);
                Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(open.FileName);

                string archivoOrigen = open.FileName;
                string rutaDestino = @"..\..\Imagenes\Imagenes_Modal\Usuario";
                string archivoDestino = System.IO.Path.Combine(rutaDestino, open.SafeFileName);

                DirectorySecurity securityRules = new DirectorySecurity();
                securityRules.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule("NQ054", FileSystemRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow));
                DirectoryInfo di = Directory.CreateDirectory(@"..\..\Imagenes\Imagenes_Modal\Usuario", securityRules);



                if (Directory.Exists(@"..\..\Imagenes\Imagenes_Modal\Usuario") == true)
                {

                    if (!di.CreateSubdirectory(@"" + valor).Exists)
                    {
                        DirectoryInfo subcarpeta = di.CreateSubdirectory(@"" + valor);
                    }
                    int fCount = Directory.GetFiles(@"..\..\Imagenes\Imagenes_Modal\Usuario\" + valor, "*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).Length;
                    string ruta = @"..\\..\\Imagenes\\Imagenes_Modal\\Usuario\\" + valor + "\\\\" + valor + fCount + ".jpeg";
                    string archivo = valor + fCount + ".jpeg";
                    File.Copy(archivoOrigen, ruta, true);
                    connection.Open(); //se abre conexion
                    string Query = "Insert Into Imagenes (Ruta, Tipo, NumeroI,Archivo,FechaCambio) values('" + ruta + "','" + valor + "',2,'" + archivo + "','"+fecha+"')";
                    MySqlCommand Conn = new MySqlCommand(Query, connection);
                    MySqlDataReader reader = Conn.ExecuteReader();
                    connection.Close(); //se cierra conexion

                }
                else
                {

                    DirectoryInfo subcarpeta = di.CreateSubdirectory(@"" + valor);
                    int fCount = Directory.GetFiles(@"..\..\Imagenes\Imagenes_Modal\Usuario\" + valor, "*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).Length;
                    string ruta = @"..\\..\\Imagenes\\Imagenes_Modal\\Usuario\\" + valor + "\\" + valor + fCount + ".jpeg";
                    string archivo = valor + fCount + ".jpeg";
                    File.Copy(archivoOrigen, archivo, true);
                    connection.Open(); // se abre conexion
                    string Query = "Insert Into Imagenes (Ruta, Tipo, NumeroI,ArchivoFechaCambio) values('" + ruta + "','" + valor + "',2,'" + archivo + "',1,'"+fecha+"')";
                    MySqlCommand Conn = new MySqlCommand(Query, connection);
                    MySqlDataReader reader = Conn.ExecuteReader();
                    connection.Close(); //se cierra conexion

                }

            }
        }

        private void btnRegresar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
            Inicio inicio = new Inicio();
            inicio.Show();
        }




    }
}
```

Codigo Completo del Formulario de Inicio:

```
namespace Presupuesto_DaeboSoft
{
    public partial class Inicio : Form
    {

        int contador = 0;

        //constructor de la clase, inicia todos los componentes
        public Inicio()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        //Metodo para no cambiar de tamaño el formulario y que se ejecute de forma central
        public void notSize()
        {
            this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedSingle;
            this.MaximizeBox = false;
            this.MinimizeBox = false;
            this.CenterToScreen();
        }

        //Metodo que carga los elementos iniciales del formulario
        private void Inicio_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            notSize();
            String quincena = calendario.TodayDate.Day.ToString();
            int dia = int.Parse(quincena);



            if (dia > 15)
            {
                lblQuincena.Text = "2";
            }
            else
            {
                lblQuincena.Text = "1";
            }

        }



        //Metodo para cerrar la aplicacion cuando el usuario guste.
        private void cierre(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
                if (e.CloseReason == CloseReason.UserClosing)
                {
                    DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("¿Esta seguro de Que quiere cerrar la aplicacion?", "Cerrar la Aplicacion", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
                    if (dialogResult != DialogResult.Yes)
                    {
                        e.Cancel = true;
                        return;
                    }

            }

        }


        //Metodo que me da la hora actual.
        private void horaActual(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            String tiempo = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
            lblTiempo.Text = "Hora Actual: " + tiempo;
        }



        //Metodo para llevarme a la ventana de Modal_General
        private void btnCompras_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
            Modal_General general = new Modal_General();
            general.Show();
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Hola David. El código tal cual no es suficiente para entender tu problema. Por favor asegúrate de que el código sea un [mcve], que es la misma sugerencia que te di en tu pregunta anterior. Solo agrego que el problema suena a que tiene que ver con el código donde se registra `cierre` para manejar el evento `Close`, pero no has mostrado esa parte de tu código.  Como te comenté en tu otra pregunta, en vez de tratar de determinar cual parte del código es relevante, incluye de una vez un [mcve].

Comment: @sstan lo siento eh modificado mi pregunta, y como ahorita no puedo hacer el ejemplo completo, no lo podre proporcionar una disculpa y no se como hacerlo. ya que siempre formulo mis preguntas de esta forma. Gracias por comentar

Comment: Aunque no puedo explicar cada detalle de lo que te está pasando, porque no es un [mcve], sí puedo decirte que el código que maneja los botones `Compras` y `Regresar` no me parecen correctos y pueden ser parte de la causa del problema.  En particular, veo que cada vez que usas esos botones, en vez de transferirte a una ventana ya existente, ***creas nuevas instancias*** de los formularios a cada vez y vas escondiendo los forumulario ya existentes. Como mínimo, esto significa que estás acumulando formularios en memoria innecesasriamente, y probablemente sea parte de la razón de tu problema.

Comment: @sstan como es que puedo trasladarme de una ventana a otra sin tener formularios inecesarios en memoria, si conoces alguna forma, me la podrias proporcionar, gracias

Comment: Es difícil contestar eso sin entender mejor el programa y como deseas manejar los diferentes formularios. Pero de una manera u otra, me suena a que necesitas guardar referencias a tus formularios en variables estáticas. Al menos eso sospecho.

Comment: @sstan lo unico que requiero es que mis formularios se enlacen y como tu dices, los que no se usan que no ocupen memoria, solamente los que se estan usando y la verdad me gustaria saber como guardar referencias de mis formularios en variables staticas para un uso posterior. seria de gran ayuda, asi por lo menos sabre si esto ocasiona mi ligero bug.

Comment: Una pregunta mas para ver si te propongo algo o no. ¿Hay una razón en particular por la que haces `this.Hide()` en vez de `this.Close()` en los event handlers?

Comment: @sstan no hay ninguna, crei que era mas eficaz aunque ya lo modifique por "this.close()" y sigue con el error.

Comment: Tendrías que probar cambiando ambos el `this.Hide()` por `this.Close()` y también eliminar la sentencia `xxx.Closed += (s, args) => this.Close();`. Y esto lo tienes que hacer en todos los event handlers que siguen este patrón. Si eso no funciona, hasta allí llego yo, y vuelvo y te sugiero de incluír un [mcve]. Esa es en realidad la forma correcta de hacer este tipo de preguntas. Evita justamente de que esté fajándome para ir averiguando detalles uno por uno a través de los comentarios.

Comment: @sstan creo que ya agregue todo el codigo que interactua, ¿esa es la forma en que se pone un Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable?, es que no creo estar seguro.

Comment: como editaste los mensajes a español?

Comment: @Rastalovely en el metodo de "cierre()", en el formulario de inicio.

Comment: Para entender lo que es un [mcve], sigue el enlace y estúdialo. La idea es que debes reducir tu programa lo mas que puedes hasta que solo te quede lo esencial para reproducir el problema. Entonces, debes incluir en tu pregunta el código necesario para que nosotros podamos simplemente copiar el código y correr el programa y reproducir el error. Por ahora, aun con tu última edición, esto no es el caso. Toma en cuenta que tus clases son parciales. Para cada formulario, hay más código, probablemente en archivos *.Designer.cs, que no has incluído. Y sospecho que el problema está allí.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
protected override void OnFormClosing(FormClosingEventArgs e)
{            
    base.OnFormClosing(e);
    if (PreClosingConfirmation() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        Dispose(true);
        Application.Exit();
    }
    else
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
}

private DialogResult PreClosingConfirmation()
{
    DialogResult res = System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("¿Esta seguro de Que quiere cerrar la aplicacion?", "Cerrar la Aplicacion", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
    return res;
}
```

Prueba este código usando `Application.Exit();` en vez de usar `Close();`.